# How to redirect Port 2083 to 2082

Tags: cpanel, whm

how to redirect Cpanel port 2083 to 2082 ? i want my Cpanel not use SSL

```
123.123.123.123:2083
```

to

```
123.123.123.123:2082
```

Comment: In WHM Tweak setting -> Require SSL. Uncheck it. That should be enough.

Comment: I know that but i want when i connect to 2083 will redirect to 2082 .

Comment: Try something like this with iptables: iptables -p tcp --dport 2083 -j REDIRECT --to-port 2082

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to do this through a rerouting, you could use IP Tables if this is Linux. Also, could you provide a bit more detail, like system info.